# React/JavaScript preload small videos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving 5 small videos in an array like:

```
const videos = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5']
```

I want to display first video, and preload / fetch rest of them and store, so when next video would be clicked then or loaded then we will not have to wait for it

Code:

```
const [currentVideo, setCurrentVideo] = useState(0);


<video
  src={url[currentVideo]}
  muted
  autoPlay
  controls
  onEnded={updateVideo}
  onLoadStart={handleLoad}
/>

const updateVideo = () => {
    const videoToWatch = video.length === currentVideo + 1 ? 0 : currentVideo + 1;
    setCurrentVideo(videoToWatch);
  };
```

How could we preload videos in React?

---

UPDATE

I found something like

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'video.mp4', true);
req.responseType = 'blob';

req.onload = function() {
   // Onload is triggered even on 404
   // so we need to check the status code
   if (this.status === 200) {
      var videoBlob = this.response;
      var vid = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob); // IE10+
      // Video is now downloaded
      // and we can set it as source on the video element
      video.src = vid;
   }
}
```

But I'm not sure how could I use it in React and Axios + update video.src

Comment: Place a second hidden `video` tag. Alternate hidden `video`  in `updateVideo`.

Comment: So you mean to create like 4 more video tags when I will have 5 videos? Isn't there more smart way?

Comment: You dont need 5 video tags. Just create 2 and hide one when showing the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to prefetch them videos

```
  <link rel="prefetch" href="short.mp4" as="video" type="video/mp4">
```

> Prefetch Specifies that the user agent should preemptively fetch and cache the target resource as it is likely to be required for a followup navigation.